# Winform menustrip and hiding tabs

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, menustrip

Hello I'm thinking of creating a tabcontrol which the tabpages will be filtered by the clicks in the menustrip.

For ex.

My menustrip is in form 1
and my tabcontrol is in form 2

My tabcontrol consist of 7 tabs and I want only 1 tab will be shown at a time.

for example If I click the name in the menustrip it will open/show a new form and the tabcontrol will only show the names tab.

I wonder if its possible because making diff forms for each list seems to be very long.

thanks for reading this.

Comment: Okay, that's pretty straight-forward. So what exactly do you want help with?

Comment: I don't know what syntax to use on this problem. I've tried to use form1.menustrip but it doesn't work =_=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is, the `TabPage` control has no `Visible` property (well, it has, but it does nothing). So you can't hide and show tabs at will. You'll have to remove the tabs that should not be visible.

You could make a form (named TabbedForm) with code like this:

```
private readonly int _index;

public TabbedForm(int index)
{
  this._index = index;
  InitializeComponent();
}

private void form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  for (int index = this.tabControl1.TabPages.Count - 1; index >= 0; index--)
  {
    if (index != this._index)
      this.tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(this.tabControl1.TabPages[index]);
  }
}
```

With each menu button (`Clicked` event) in your main form you can open a TabbedForm with a different index.

Comment: @rjtubera: Added last sentence after your comment above. Is this clear to you?

Comment: Thank You very Much mr. GertArnold this really helped alot :))

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this will work pretty fine. But I think, you must use the default tab view control for this and that must not create the problem either in you case too.

Comment: Add some snapshot of what you have done uptil now, also specify the code.

Comment: could you not just put a link about the tutorial about this thing? I have reallly no idea on how to do it. I couldn't even start.