# C# Winform Hiding/Showing Tabs

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

is it possible to hide tab and whenever I press a button it will appear?

what i mean by tab is the next tab not the tabcontrol itself the tab header (or whatever it is called).

Thank You Very Much!!! I hope my sincere appreciation will awaken your hearts to answer this simple question.

Comment: What was wrong with the answer you got  [the last time you asked this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352121/winform-menustrip-and-hiding-tabs)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hiding tab:

`tabControl2.TabPages.Remove(tabPage4);` where `tabPage4` is the name of the tab

showing tab:

`tabControl2.TabPages.Add(tabPage4);`

[here's the link](http://en.csharp-online.net/TabControl)

Comment: Removal of the tab object and creation of a new tab object are not quite the same thing as 'hiding' and 'showing'. It gives the same visual appearance (granted you've written the tab generation code to recreate the tab as it was originally) but it is heavy. In reality this is not possible with the standard Tab control's built in abilities.

Comment: @johntotetwo: sir can I ask additional question? it already added 1 tab but I want it to point to that tab. How can I do that? It only adds tab but it doesn't go to that tab.

Comment: `tabControl2.SelectedTab = tabPage4`;

Comment: How can i again add the tab in tab Control to a specific index